# Print with less(1) from C

Tags: c, pipe, posix, less-unix

I would like to print a big matrix of data which I have in a linked list.  It doesn't fit into a terminal (80 lines), so it is inconvenient to print it with standard printing functions; and `less` is already invented, so I wouldn't want to be reinventing it using ncurses; so I want to pass some `printf`d lines to `less`.

My first guess would be to write to a file, and then `system("less -S file");`, and then delete the file.

A more complicated solution would be to rewrite less so that its `main()` is converted to a `less()` function that I can call from C, and instead of a filename string I could provide it with a file descriptor or a stream.

Is there any way that doesn't involve needing to create a file and also not needing to rewrite (part of) less?

Comment: I assume the obvious way of external `./program > less` is unsuitable?

Comment: Yes, it is unsuitable

Comment: I think the suggestion should have been `./program | less`.  You could consider using `FILE *fp = popen("less", "w");` and then writing all output to `fp`.  You'd use `pclose()` to close the stream when you've finished writing to it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  `popen()` is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider using POSIX functions [`popen()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html) and [`pclose()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pclose.html).

You'd use:

```
FILE *fp = popen("less", "w");

if (fp != NULL)
{
    …write output to fp…
    pclose(fp);
}
else
    …report error…
```

Note that the `pclose()` will wait for `less` to exit.  If you want to, you can capture the return value from `pclose()` and analyze it.  See [How to detect if shell failed to execute a command after `popen()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60013021/16138) for discussion of this.

Comment: For those who read this question in the future:  there is one little difference to shell `| less` in this code.  Apparently, "you can't use Ctrl+C to stop skipping to the end of the output without killing both less and the original program".  Source: [Piping into pager (less) from C program](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=159460).  It may or may not be a problem.

Comment: Use `q` instead of Control-C (or whatever your interrupt key is) to exit from `less`.  You could consider adding signal handling to your program, but it isn't trivial to get right — you probably end up simulating `popen()` and `pclose()` rather than using them.

Comment: Actually that's not a problem for me, but after reading your answer, I googled it and found that difference.  As I understood it, it's not a problem about closing `less`, but about stopping it from something that it's doing. From `man less`: *"Normally, an interrupt character causes less to stop whatever it is doing and return to its command prompt."*.  I have never used that command in less before, however.  For my usage, `popen()` is just perfect.  I guess, as you said, that catching the signal in the program and passing the interrupt character through the stream would solve that.