# How does parent process convert child process exit code to status code?

Tags: c, process, waitpid

When I run the following code (headers and main entry ommitted)

```
void fork11()
{
    pid_t pid[N];
    int i;
    int child_status;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    if ((pid[i] = fork()) == 0)
        exit(100+i); /* Child */
    for (i = N-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        pid_t wpid = waitpid(pid[i], &child_status, 0);
        if (WIFEXITED(child_status)) {
            printf("Child %d terminated with exit status %d\n", wpid, WEXITSTATUS(child_status));
            printf("child_status: %d\n", child_status);
        } else {            
            printf("Child %d terminate abnormally\n", wpid);
        }    
    }
}
```

the result is

```
Child 5126 terminated with exit status 104
child_status: 26624
Child 5125 terminated with exit status 103
child_status: 26368
Child 5124 terminated with exit status 102
child_status: 26112
Child 5123 terminated with exit status 101
child_status: 25856
Child 5122 terminated with exit status 100
child_status: 25600
```

with some digging around I find `WEXITSTATUS` is a simple macro

`#define WEXITSTATUS(x) ((_W_INT(x) >> 8) & 0x000000ff)`

take child process 5126 for example, `waitpid` converts `104` to `26624=0x6800`, `WEXITSTATUS` converts `26624` back to `104=0x68`, I tried to look up source code of `waitpid` but ended up with some kernel functions [which I can't understand](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/waitpid.c.html#34)... could anyone explain a little bit about how does `waitpid` convert exit code? It seems fairly simple in the above example but I think it's much more than that, thanks!

Comment: I have a somehow similar question about an exit status, [How to detect if shell failed to execute a command after popen call? Not to confuse with the command exit status](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60013200/8339821). My understanding is that process mail fail, process may be signaled, and shell may fail. Hope you will find some useful information in the answer I've linked.

Comment: @ЯрославМашко thanks mate it's very helpful, I still wonder what else is going on besides shifting bits around...

Comment: If you're using glibc, you'll want to look at https://code.woboq.org/gcc/include/bits/waitstatus.h.html

Comment: @ЯрославМашко thank you mate, i was looking for that answer too. Have a nice day.

Comment: shift and mask... what else can? or you talking about some other process activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a process exits, the return value passed to the `exit()` function is used as a parameter for the actual `int` (4 bytes) passed to any process that waits for it. In addition to the 8 bits of this status code, more information is being passed.

For example, in the actual (final) exit code (the entire 4 bytes), it's being specified whether the process was signaled or not.

As seen [here](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) about `WEXITSTATUS`:

> This consists of the least significant 8 bits of the status argument that the child specified in a call to `exit(3)`...

This means that processes cannot exit with codes that require more than 8 bits.